# sql server stored procedure to return selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I cannot get the following stored procedure in classic asp code to work. It should return the data row. I would appreciate your help. thanks

code:

```
Set cmdSessionProc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdSessionProc.ActiveConnection = conn
cmdSessionProc.CommandText = "GetDetails"
cmdSessionProc.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("RetVal", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
cmdSessionProc.Parameters.Append 
   cmdSessionProc.CreateParameter "SessionID", adInteger, adParamReturnValue 
cmdSessionProc("SessionID")= required data value (int)
cmdSessionProc.execute


ALTER Procedure [xxxxxxx].[GetDetails]
(@ID   int)
AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM [xxxtablexxx] 
    WHERE [ID] = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

In classic VB, `Execute` returns a `ADODB.Recordset`.  You can read it something like:

```
Set rstRecordSet = cmdSessionProc.execute
For i = 1 To rstRecordSet.RecordCount
    MsgBox rstRecordSet.Fields(0).Name & "=" & rstRecordSet.Fields(0)
    rstRecordSet.MoveNext
Next
rstRecordSet.Close
```

There are [good examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your help. I eventually put together the following code which seems to work well.
'* get session details
DIM cmdSessionProc ' Command object
DIM rstSessionProc

Set cmdSessionProc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmdSessionProc
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandText = "GetSessionData"
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Parameters.Append .createParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput,, strSessionID)
end with
SET rstSessionProc = cmdSessionProc.Execute
strSessionID=cmdSessionProc.Parameters("@ID")
response.redirect("xxx.asp?id=" & strSessionID)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andomar's answer of actually reading the resultset, I noticed that you have have some other issues too.

- You obscured the stored proc's schema with xxxxxxx. If the schema is something other than the default for the user specified in your connection string (typically dbo), you should specify the schema in the CommandText also , that is `cmdSessionProc.CommandText = "xxxxxxx.GetDetails"`. Actually, you should *always* specify the schema anyway and not let it default for performance reasons.
- Your stored procedure has 1 parameter @ID, but your sample code is specifying 2 parameters, "RetValue" for the return value (that's OK) and SessionID ***also as a return value***. That second one needs to be `adParamInput` and the name must match the stored proc's parameter name (because you don't have to create parameters in the same order as they are in the proc). In fact, I believe you need to have the @ sign in the string too. `cmdSessionProc.Parameters.Append cmdSessionProc.CreateParameter "@ID", adInteger, adParamInput`

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. 
DIM cmdSessionProc ' Command object
DIM rstSessionProc

Set cmdSessionProc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmdSessionProc
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandText = "GetSessionData"
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Parameters.Append .createParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput,, strSessionID)
end with
SET rstSessionProc = cmdSessionProc.Execute
strSessionID=cmdSessionProc.Parameters("@ID")
response.redirect("xxx.asp?id=" & strSessionID)

Answer (score 0):

i make a function for all pages, even standard query or SP i use this method.
try this, hope it works for you.

```
dsn = "" 'your SQL connection param
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.mode = 3
conn.Open dsn
sql = "exec GetDetails 'yourparam1','yourparam2'"
rs.open sql, conn
'codes to manage the results here
'......
```